# How to wait for a mongoose .exec() callback to finish executing before testing for express response object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I am working on an application that uses Express and Mongoose, and is tested with Jest. I currently have a mongodb that is set up in local memory for testing purposes. I am running into a problem in several of my tests wherein a mongoose query's `.exec()` callback is not finished executing before I actually test the values I need to.

A function I am trying to test:⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

```js
exports.getLinksRulesAll = function(req, res, next) {
    linkFindAll(req, res, next, LinksRules);
}

function linkFindAll(req, res, next, ruleOrHistory) {
    // Sort by date, descending
    ruleOrHistory.find().sort({dateClicked: -1}).exec(
        function(err, links) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send({message: "Error"});
                return;
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    links: links
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

For reference, LinksRules is a simple mongoose model.

Here are tests I have for this function:

```js
const mockRes = () => {
    const res = {};

    res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
    res.send = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
    res.json = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();

    return res;
};

describe("links.controller.getLinksRulesAll", () => {
    it("Provide a valid linkRule.", async () => {
        const partner = await createPartnership();
        const id = await insertLinkRule(partner._id);

        const res = mockRes();

        linksCon.getLinksRulesAll({}, res, () => {});

        expect(res.send).not.toBeCalled();
        expect(res.status).toBeCalled();
        expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
        expect(res.json).toBeCalled();
    });

    it("Provide no linkRules.", async () => {
        const res = mockRes();

        linksCon.getLinksRulesAll({}, res, () => {});

        expect(res.json).not.toBeCalled();
        expect(res.status).toBeCalled();
        expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(400);
        expect(res.send).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

`createPartnership()` inserts a `Partnership` into the local mongodb, as a `LinksRule` is reliant on a `Partnership`.

The problem for this function (and many others) is the fact that mocked `res.status` object shows no calls being made to it. I have tried `console.log(res.status.mock.calls)` and it has shown that the callback is being executed with the right arguments, but the Jest test is finishing before that finishes. I have tried using `done()`, I have tried using the `thenable` aspect of mongoose queries, and I have tried wrapping the `linksCon.getLinksRulesAll()` function call into a promise to no avail.

How can I wait for the `.exec()` callback to finish executing before my Jest test's `expect()` calls execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably by dropping the callback syntax and using `async/await`? I'm not sure but it might solve the testing problem.

```
async function linkFindAll(req, res, next, ruleOrHistory) {
    try {
        const links = await ruleOrHistory
                        .find()
                        .sort({dateClicked: -1})
                        .lean() // Get pure JSON, not a collection of Mongoose objects (faster)
                        .exec(); // return a true Promise, not a thenable

        res.status(200).json({links});
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(400).send({message: "Error"});
    }
}
```